# Adding links to Comments

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

While giving comments many times I wanted to add links to my comment. But instead of using some short hand like `Read "this" (this is a link in this case)` I had to write `Read "http:\\www.somelink.com"`. I tried  <kbd>ctrl+L</kbd> to insert a link to my comment but it was of no use.

I have seen people inserting links to their comments in the above mentioned way. How? Hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: See [How does the comment system and comments work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757)

Comment: Update, [does it still work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/how-do-i-add-code-while-writing-comments) Yes, it does.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757)

Spoiler:

```
[link text](https://www.example.com)
```

Comment: finally I have found it :) many thanks to @PrasoonSaurav for the question and to user27414 for this answer

Comment: What about links containing '(' and ')' like this one: http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc784450(v=ws.10).aspx ?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo - `%28` and `%29` can be used for `(` and `)` respectively, just like `%20` can be used to represent a space.  [YourExample](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc784450%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) = `[YourExample](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc784450%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)`

Comment: this is working for http urls .but if i want to comment special urls for example firefox about:addons link? when i comment [addon page][bout:addons] see it's not working is there a way to comment as a click-able link ?

Comment: I do not get why is the syntax different than the one for adding comments in questions/answers bodies

Comment: [link text](http://www.example.com)

Comment: I think that's because `lightning:tab` is in Beta right now(But not sure why they haven't mentioned that in the link which you've included in the question). 
[lightning:tab (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_components_considerations.htm) @TrevorBliss @JFParadis

Comment: Yes, the above method is the solution to put insert the link. But one caution that you should insert `HTTP://` before your link. Otherwise, it will not be linked.

Comment: I think this is the first time I see a banned person answer. Pity, got my vote on the "Spoiler" :D

Comment: [link try]  (https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: [lets see](https://about:blank)