# How do I add code while writing comments?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

How do I add code while writing comments and how do I enter a newline character?

Comment: Writing what comments? Not sure I understand

Comment: While commenting to an answer / question.. When i hav to include a code sample, there s not formattin option lik available for asking a question

Comment: Like this: `This is code`.

Comment: You don't add newlines in comments. If you want to post that much code edit your question (or answer) or post an answer.

Comment: wait, so you can't write code in comments with more than 1 line?

Comment: @CharlieParker - Unfortunately, that's correct. Well, you can insert one or more newlines into comments, and the newlines will be preserved, but they will not be displayed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can't put newlines in a comment codeblock, but you can do inline code by using the backtick character. It looks like this

> `

and it appears below the escape key on most keyboards which is sometimes the same key as the tilde (for example, on US English keyboards):

> ~

Surrounding something in backticks lets it appear as an "inline code block" and you could `put them almost` anywhere you like, even breaking across new lines. `int c; c++; sprintf();` but notice there's no coloration, of course.

E.g. typing `something` in the editor produces `something` on the page

Comment: Better to upvote or accept, but I'll take the thanks for now ;)

Comment: `test
code`
not code

Comment: 'something' this is a test

Comment: ~something~ this is another test

Comment: `one more time` , cool

Comment: `this` is `just` a `test`

Comment: you need to place the symbol just before the letter, and no spacing between the back quote and `starting` letter.  ` FYI`  :P

Comment: test `code` in comments

Comment: Thanks. I thought they meant the single quote '. Luckily I found this answer in under 4 minutes or I could have earned the "Can't tell a backtick from a single quote" badge.

Comment: this is `test` command

Comment: This is a `test`

Comment: And now you're flooded with a bunch of `test codes` comments.

Comment: This is a test because this was not working for me `ok`? <br> This is not giving me a line break. I cannot line break.  /sigh

Comment: Not in comments you can't

Comment: Just an update, `does it still work?` Yes, it does.

Comment: I'm not seeing a newline lol

Comment: I want `code` to appear in next line. How to put `n newline

Comment: Testing... `code`

Comment: `testing code code`

Comment: trying `to get this to work~ it didn't what about ` this`

Comment: What are you trying to do @himanshuxd?

Comment: @jcolebrand ah I was trying to get `this` to work and it finally did, just testing it out ig, codeblocks in android is complicated, sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: Oh you aren't messing with me @himanshuxd I just like to pitch in where I can :-)

Comment: @jcolebrand thanks finding backticks on android is hard wish Gboard had custom keys for alphanumeric long presses.

Comment: `okay` does this work

Comment: that answered my question, can you also help me with the further error ` 'hello.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` , hello.txt is the file that I wanted to open

Comment: why did it not work in the previous comment?

Comment: this is just a `simple test`. do you work?

Comment: `isItWork = yes it is`

Comment: First and `only test

Comment: nevermind `only`

Comment: This is a `test`

Comment: `"\\[*\\].*\\[*\\].*\\[*\\].*"`

Answer (score 7):

Place this symbol: ` before and after the code. (On many keyboards, this "[backtick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick)" is the button to the left of "1".)

Comment: @CHID: like drachenstern said, better to upvote or accept.  ;)

Comment: ¨ds¨  test vfdsfds